# Convert Feb 17, 2012 to 17/02/2012 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var Date = "Feb 17, 2012";
```

How can I convert it to

```
Date = "17/02/2012"
```

using jQuery?

Comment: Why jQuery? It is primarily a DOM and Ajax library, not a general purpose one.

Comment: And why are you overwriting the global Date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Date()` constructor to parse your date :

```
var mydate = new Date("Feb 17, 2012");
```

then you have to build up your required format as follows, in this case `DD/MM/YYYY` :

```
var newdate = mydate.getDate() + '/' +
              ("0" + (parseInt(mydate.getMonth())+1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
               mydate.getFullYear();
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/bd3sa/2/

[Docs on Date object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Another question if I may: How can I convert "2012-02-12" to "12/02/2012"

Answer (score 3):

Converting with DateJs should be as easy as:

```
var d1 = Date.parse('2010-10-18, 10:06 AM');
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT'));
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? it doesnt work ...http://jsfiddle.net/y459y/ toString() does not have any parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="tbDateTime" value="2010-10-18 10:06" />
<input type="text" id="tbDate" value="" />
<input type="text" id="tbTime" value="" />

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var dateTimeSplit = $('#tbDateTime').val().split(' ');

            var dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('-');
            var currentDate = dateSplit[2] + '/' + dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[0];
            //currentDate is 18/10/2010

            $('#tbDate').val(currentDate);

            var currentTime = dateTimeSplit[1];
            //currentTime is 10:06

            $('#tbTime').val(currentTime);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI, you can do:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd/mm/yy", new Date("Feb 17, 2012") )
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wztEA/